# Variable not visible inside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I have a for loop in JavaScript like

```
var loopvariable = 0;  
let row = [[]];
for (var key in supplies.food) {
     row[loopvariable][0] = key;
     row[loopvariable][1] = supplies.food[key];
     loopvariable++;
}
```

why am i getting the following error

> TypeError: row[loopvariable] is undefined

Comment: For future questions, please include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). You've said in a comment on my answer that `supplies.food` is an array. That's surprising, because `for-in` isn't the correct way to loop through arrays. If you provide complete information, it makes it possible to help you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable

```
row[loopvariable]
```

is not initialized. You could use a default value and take an array with a guard operator ([logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())).

```
row[loopvariable] = row[loopvariable] || [];
```

A shorter approach could be just to push a new array to `row`, without using an aditional variable `loopvariable`

```
let row = [];
for (var key in supplies.food) {
    row.push([key, supplies.food[key]]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) provides exact the output you're trying to create there:

```
let row = Object.entries(supplies.food);
```

### Details, and why your code isn't working

You've only created an array at `row[0]`, not at `row[1]` (`row[2]`, `row[3]`, ...), but then you're trying to use an array at `row[1]` on the second iteration of the loop.

The minimal change is to leave the creation of the inner arrays to the loop body:

```
var loopvariable = 0;  
let row = [];                                      // ***
for (var key in supplies.food) {
     row[loopvariable] = [];                       // ***
     row[loopvariable][0] = key;
     row[loopvariable][1] = supplies.food[key];
     loopvariable++;
}
```

But we can also use an array initializer to be more concise:

```
var loopvariable = 0;  
let row = [];
for (var key in supplies.food) {
     row[loopvariable++] = [
         key,
         supplies.food[key]
     ];
}
```

But, again, for this specific case you can just use `Object.entries`:

```
let row = Object.entries(supplies.food);
```

Live Example:

```js
const supplies = {
  food: {
    water: "3l",
    bread: "2 loaves",
    chocolate: "4 bars"
  }
};
let row = Object.entries(supplies.food);
console.log(row);
```

`Object.entries` is supported in all modern environments, and easily polyfilled in older environments.

In a comment you've said `supplies.food` is an array. If so, `for-in` isn't the right way to loop through it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for details), but `Object.entries` still works because arrays are objects, too (see [my blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) for more):

```js
const supplies = {
  food: [
    "3l water",
    "2 loaves bread",
    "4 bars chocolate"
  ]
};
let row = Object.entries(supplies.food);
console.log(row);
```

Comment: @akshaykishore - Actually, looking at the array you're producing, it's exactly what you'd get from `Object.entries`, I've added to the end of my answer.

Comment: actually food here is an array not an object so i don't know if that'll work or not

Comment: @akshaykishore - Yes, it will (because arrays are objects, too). But `for-in` isn't the right way to loop through arrays. I've added to the end of the answer with details.